# Trying to remove 1152 samples, but the queue is empty

Tags: ffmpeg, nginx, audio-streaming, ffserver

I am streaming mp3 files,using this command :

```
ffmpeg -re -i 'INPUT.mp3' -map_metadata -1 -map 0:0 URL
```

I create a loop which stream files,and there is no problem with reviving stream,just from server I get this error

```
[libmp3lame @ 0x25088e0] Trying to remove 1152 samples, but the queue is empty
```

from another answer in here I added the -write_xing 0 option,but still I got this error
any idea how to solve it ?

Here is a complete output console

```
  ffmpeg version git-2014-08-13-e3212bf Copyright (c) 2000-2014 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Aug 13 2014 10:47:41 with gcc 4.4.7 (GCC) 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-4)
  configuration: --prefix=/root/ffmpeg_build --extra-cflags=-I/root/ffmpeg_build/include --extra-ldflags=-L/root/ffmpeg_build/lib --bindir=/root/bin --extra-libs=-ldl --enable-gpl --enable-nonfree --enable-libfdk_aac --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora
  libavutil      54.  1.100 / 54.  1.100
  libavcodec     56.  0.100 / 56.  0.100
  libavformat    56.  0.100 / 56.  0.100
  libavdevice    56.  0.100 / 56.  0.100
  libavfilter     5.  0.100 /  5.  0.100
  libswscale      3.  0.100 /  3.  0.100
  libswresample   1.  0.100 /  1.  0.100
  libpostproc    53.  0.100 / 53.  0.100
Input #0, mp3, from './musics/3 doors down/Away From The Sun/This Time.mp3':
  Metadata:
    album           : away from the sun
    artist          :  3doorsdown
  Duration: 00:05:19.06, start: 0.025056, bitrate: 321 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Audio: mp3, 44100 Hz, stereo, s16p, 320 kb/s
    Metadata:
      encoder         : LAME3.93 
    Stream #0:1: Video: mjpeg, yuvj444p(pc, bt470bg), 659x501 [SAR 1:1 DAR 659:501], 90k tbr, 90k tbn, 90k tbc
    Metadata:
      title           : 
      comment         : Cover (front)
Output #0, ffm, to 'http://127.0.0.1:8090/pop.ffm':
  Metadata:
    creation_time   : now
    encoder         : Lavf56.0.100
    Stream #0:0: Audio: mp3 (libmp3lame), 44100 Hz, mono, s32p, 128 kb/s
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc56.0.100 libmp3lame
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (mp3 (native) -> mp3 (libmp3lame))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[libmp3lame @ 0x3bc9860] Trying to remove 1152 samples, but the queue is empty
size=    5200kB time=00:05:19.05 bitrate= 133.5kbits/s    
video:0kB audio:4986kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 4.298003%
```

Comment: -write_xing 0 will make the problem even worse, the wrong values are written into xing: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/9755#comment:16